# Woocommerce loop title location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Building custom woocommerce template on top of storefront.

I want to replace/change some html for the individual item titles within the loop functionality for the category pages. The "add to cart" link, price, etc. are all located in `woocommerce/templates/loop` directory. None of the files in that directory appear contain the html for the product title for this functionality.

Where do I find this thing? I swear the most annoying thing about building on woocommerce is trying to find where all the pieces live...

Answer (score 2):

Like Randy wrote it, this is a pluggable function you will find in

`wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title' ) ) {

    /**
     * Show the product title in the product loop. By default this is an H2.
     */
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
        echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    }
}
```

To override it, just copy paste the code without the condition in the functions.php file of your child theme and modify it according to your needs.

Ex: Change h2 for h3

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
   echo '<h3 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`

`woocommerce_template_loop_product_title` function

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    echo '<h3 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need change the information in the file functions.php, preferably in the theme child file.
What you put there will normally be rewritten because it have priority.